# Why are U locks required when using Read Committed Snapshot Isolation

Tags: sql-server, locking, deadlock, isolation-level, snapshot-isolation

I consider myself a beginner at Sql Server locking.

My understanding is that when using RCSI, Sql Server doesn't need to issue S locks because it uses row versioning (in most cases). From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598(v=sql.110).aspx we can read the following about U locks:

> *Used on resources that can be updated. Prevents a common form of deadlock that occurs when multiple sessions are reading, locking, and potentially updating resources later.*

Knowing this, why does Sql Server need to issue U locks (when using RCSI)?
It seems to me that Sql Server could simply read the rows, and request a X lock directly if an update must be performed.

The reason I've been thinking about this is because of deadlocks I'm experiencing with 2 sessions updating the same table. Something like this (simplified for clarity):

Session 1:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE col2 = value1
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE col2 = value2
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE col2 = value3
```

Session 2:

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE indexedcol = value4
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE indexedcol = value5
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 100 WHERE indexedcol = value6
```

From what I gather in the Profiler lock report, both sessions have an X lock on some rows of the table, and are requesting U lock on each other's X-locked row => deadlock.
However, I know for a fact that each concurrent session will always modify different rows because the value X will never be the same in 2 different concurrent sessions.
That is, if those sessions were able to get their requested U lock, sql server would realize it is not necessary to upgrade an X lock anyway.

In conclusion I feel like, even though U locks are supposed to reduce deadlocks, they actually are creating an unnecessary deadlock here.

I understand they can be valuable for other isolation levels, but for RCSI, I don't get it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Knowing this, why does sql server need to issue U locks (when using RCSI)? It seems to me that sql server could simply read the rows, and
>   request a X lock directly if an update must be performed.*

Unlike SI, RCSI does not detect update conflicts. As [documented in Books Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189050(v=sql.105)), modifying data under RCSI reads currently-committed data, not a possibly out-of date version. (In the absence of update conflict detection, performing updates based on out-of-date data could result in a "lost update".)

Taking update locks is normal behaviour for a non-row-versioning query that updates data. It is a protection against a common cause of conversion deadlock, but it does not guarantee deadlock avoidance in all cases, especially where a different access path (index) is used to qualify rows to change.

You can find more details about the exact behaviour of RCSI when modifying data in my SQLperformance.com article, ["Data Modifications Under Read Committed Snapshot Isolation"](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/data-modifications-under-rcsi). There is further background on RCSI in general in the article, ["Read Committed Snapshot Isolation"](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation).

If the updates really are disjoint, you might consider performing the change using [Snapshot Isolation](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/sql-performance/the-snapshot-isolation-level) rather than RCSI (which admittedly has complex behaviour in this area).